# hide input field but keep autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to have a hidden email input field which only purpose is to get the email autocomplete without being shown. I tried with `type='hidden'` and `display none`, which doesn't make it work. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to show instead of the input field then?

Comment: @AlexGru nothing, it should just be hidden

Comment: Upload the code snippet please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just figured it out. Just to be clear, I needed an extra input that would catch the browser autocomplete, but I needed it to be hidden. Solved it with z-index -10

Answer (score 0):

there is a visibility. Try this:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't make it work either

Comment: I think there is no other way to be hidden, what do you mean with autocomplete?

Comment: I posted the answer. Just needed to change z-index to have it hidden but still working. Thank you